# How to downgrade R version 3.2.2 to version 3.1.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: r

I installed it using apt get and it now says 3.2.2 - this is an offending version.  How do I downgrade to 3.1.1?

Update:

```
install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table", "doMC", "doSNOW", "ggplot2", "glmnet", "lda", "Matrix", "matrixStats", "moments", "plotrix", "psych", "reshape", "topicmodels", "wordcloud", "methods"), dependencies=TRUE)

Warning messages:
1: package ‘methods’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2) 
2: In install.packages(c("boot", "caTools", "data.table", "doMC", "doSNOW",  :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(c("boot", "caTools", "data.table", "doMC", "doSNOW",  :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages(c("boot", "caTools", "data.table", "doMC", "doSNOW",  :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages(c("boot", "caTools", "data.table", "doMC", "doSNOW",  :
  installation of package ‘OAIHarvester’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages(c("boot", "caTools", "data.table", "doMC", "doSNOW",  :
  installation of package ‘topicmodels’ had non-zero exit status
```

How do I downgrade?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/435232/install-older-version-of-software-and-dependencies

Comment: "Known issue: package 'methods' is not available for R version 3.2.1. In which case, please downgrade R to version 3.1.1" - I freshly installed R now from scratch.

Comment: But `methods` is a default package, coming with any installation of R.

Comment: But they are saying it is not avail in 3.2.1. THis fails: install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table", "doMC", "doSNOW", "ggplot2", "glmnet", "lda", "Matrix", "matrixStats", "moments", "plotrix", "psych", "reshape", "topicmodels", "wordcloud", "methods"), dependencies=TRUE) - Error: Installing packages into ‘/home/vmuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error: Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: Why do you try to install all those packages at once? It might be better to try to install each package individually and then see where the error occurs.

Comment: It is CA CRAN mirror  bad. Works on another. THanks

Comment: Could u confirm that methods is truly available in all R versions a you said earlier?

Comment: `methods` is part of the `utils` package, which is included in base R.

Comment: @Pascal. If you type `methods` in the console, the last line in the function description is `<environment: namespace:utils>`. Yes, you can load `methods` as an independent library, but you can also call it with `utils::methods`.

Comment: Actually, it says WARNING: " package ‘methods’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)". Updated post with all the warning messages. So Can I downgrade to an earlier version?

Comment: Just an FYI: the methods package is different from the S3-related function `utils::methods`.

Answer (score 38):

So I've encountered the same problem recently. 
Here's a solution:

1. Remove the currently installed R version,

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
2. Find the version you need by,

   ```
   apt-cache showpkg r-base
   ```

It will look like the following:

```
Package: r-base
Versions: 
3.2.2-1precise0     (/var/lib/apt/lists/cran.rstudio.com_bin_linux_ubuntu_precise_Packages)
 Description Language: 
             File:     /var/lib/apt/lists/cran.rstudio.com_bin_linux_ubuntu_precise_Packages
              MD5: 5787ca79ed716232c4cc2087ed9b425b
```

After that, look for the required version and install it.
But, the installation of the r-base will throw errors again, so just execute:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core=3.1.1-1precise0
```

Comment: You should maybe specify that `precise` refers to the Ubuntu installation. For me for example it was `trusty`.

Comment: More informaton on @MERose comment: [Ubuntu Releases list](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)... Ubuntu 14.04 is `trusty`, etc.

Comment: The solution also works if you want to downgrade from R 4.1 to the latest R 4.0.

Comment: Great solution!!! This also works if you want to downgrade from R 4.2.0 to R 4.1.3!

Comment: After downgrading, what happens if a new upgrade of `r-base-core` becomes available? Is there a way to prevent the downgraded version to be upgraded?