# How to downgrade R version from 3.5 to 3.4 in Linux?

Tags: linux, package, yum, downgrade

Recently I upgraded R version from my linux box. It upgraded from 3.3 to 3.5, but as per the requirement I need to downgrade it to R version 3.4.2. 
I tried yum downgrade R but it is not working. 
Any help on this ?

Comment: This is not about R or linux, it's about your distro (of linux). Since you mentioned `yum`, you can probably find something at superuser: https://superuser.com/search?q=yum+downgrade+package.

Comment: Also: *"I tried yum downgrade R but it is not working."* is very unspecific. What does that mean "not working". Did it produce an error? A warning? What was the command you used? Potentially relevant is this post: [Installing multiple versions of R on Linux](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215488098-Installing-multiple-versions-of-R-on-Linux) which includes examples for both RedHat and Ubuntu derivatives.

Comment: The cleanest way, in my opinion, would be to uninstall R and start over with the right version

Comment: It is in production environment and I guess uninstalling it won't be a great idea.

Comment: When I try "yum downgrade R" , I get a message nothing to do.

Comment: @ShubhamShekhar Well, `"yum downgrade R"` is obviously not a valid `yum downgrade` command. You need to give a specific package version, see e.g. the basic [how to yum downgrade](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29617) advice. Personally, I'd recommend installing multiple R versions side-by-side, especially if you are working with different R environments. I've given a link in my previous comment that provides very comprehensive instructions.

Comment: @MauritsEvers  Thank you so much for your help. It worked. Now, I have 2 versions of R installed.

Comment: This answer to a similar question on SO, provides a different answer; `https://stackoverflow.com/a/34070419/410975`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow our team managed to find a workaround for this problem. Instead of downgrading the current version of R(3.5), we decided to install R(3.4.2) and keep both the versions. I followed this document on the same :-

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218004217-Building-R-from-source

It helps and now my default R library has been set to 3.4.2 which solves my problem.